# Autodesk forge Usage Analytics won't show any data

Tags: autodesk-forge

I can't see Usage Analytics after using Derivative api.
I see only current credit balance on Autodesk account page, but I need informations about consumption of my apps separately.

Only for first Billing period it's shown detail data correctly (other two months are empty).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately as of now our usage analytics still can’t break usage data down by apps yet - will let our Engineering know it’s good to have the breakdown available and update this answer when it’s there.